# How to insert md file contents into html textarea?

Tags: jquery, markdown

Is it possible to insert md file to html text area? If so how do I go about doing this?

I tried the following:

```
<html>
<head>

 <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script src='https://gnab.github.io/remark/downloads/remark-latest.min.js'></script>
      <script>  

    $('#source').load('test.md', function() {
        var slideshow = remark.create();
    });


      </script>
</head>
<body>
<textarea id=source>
</textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

I am not sure what is wrong? I got the code from a differet forum which they say it is working fine but it is not working for me, do I have to give any permission to my server on 1and1 to read the file etc?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't see anything. It is just blank.

Comment: @David How to check ajax request to the MD files URL is being made?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is executing before the target element exists, so this selector finds nothing:

```
$('#source')
```

Your choices are to either execute the code at the end of the page, or wrap it in a `document.ready` handler:

```
$(function () {
    $('#source').load('test.md', function() {
        var slideshow = remark.create();
    });
});
```

Comment: Now the md file shows but it doesn't show inside the text area instead it shows fully like PDF on Chrome.

Comment: @SanjanaNair: What is `remark.create()`?  Is that affecting it?  Try removing that.

Comment: will try and let you know. Thanks!